# Better Approach to fetch entire data from the table Groovy Sql

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I am trying to fetch entire data from a table and the outcome should be a comma separated string. Here is my code which is working fine.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;

def temp=""; 
def temp1=""; 
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","username", "password", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") 
sql.eachRow("select * FROM employee") { 
temp1=it.toRowResult().values().join(", ") 
if(temp=="") 
            { 
             temp=temp1; 
            } 
else 
            { 
             temp=temp+"\n"+temp1 
            } 

}
```

Kindly suggest if there is any better approach to handle this requirement in Groovy.

Comment: Is the idea to store into `csv` file?

Comment: No not into a csv but when I do a select operation I need the the fetch the table data in the form of comma separated values. I want to store it in a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keep it simple solution is the following:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;

Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","username", "password", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") 

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()

sql.eachRow("select * FROM employee") { row -> 
   builder.append( "${row.employeeId}," ) // no idea what your column names are
} 

return builder.toString()  // should trim trailing comma but I'll save that for you
```

You may also be able to do this with inject(), but I've not tried that on a SQL result set before.

Comment: I do not want to specify the column names rather it should read the data of all the columns where comma should be the delimiter for each and every column value. Is there any way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: If you don't want to use column names, you can use column position integer values. However, a "select *" is not very specific about the order of the columns returned. You would need to add the column names to the select statement to guarantee the order of the result and thus refer to them by position.